# No puedo hacer funcionar Django-registration con Custom user model

Tags: django

Hola soy novato en Django y estoy usando django-registration porque me gusta como resuelve en forma sencilla el registro en dos fases. Mi inconveniente es que al modificar mi modelo (User) no encuentro la forma de hacer funcionar el registro de usuario. Sé que necesito definir un RegistrationForm pero no puedo hacerlo funcionar.
Gracias.

models.py

```
class Usuario(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField('email', max_length=254, unique=True, help_text="Email válido")
username = models.CharField('username', max_length=100, unique=True, help_text="Username (i.e juan-perez)")
first_name = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Nombres")
last_name = models.CharField('apellido', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Apellido")
date_joined = models.DateTimeField('fecha de alta', auto_now_add=True)
last_login= models.DateTimeField('último login', auto_now=True)
birth_date = models.DateTimeField('fecha de nacimiento', blank=True, null=True, help_text="Fecha de nacimiento: (DD/MM/AAAA)")
country= models.CharField('país', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, help_text="(i.e Argentina)")
city= models.CharField('ciudad', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, help_text="")
is_admin= models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active= models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff= models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country']
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Usuario
    fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']

class registro(RegistrationForm):
model = Usuario
form_class = UserForm
template_name = 'django_registration/registration_form.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('sitio:index')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('accounts/register/', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=registro),name='django_registration_register',),
path('accounts/', include('django_registration.backends.activation.urls')
),
```

]

Comment: Hola Leo, ¿Que es lo que no funciona? Por favor lee [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y de una ves revisa el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Leo la clase `registro`, **es un formulario** y lo estas tratando como una vista (por sus atributos), esta heredando del formulario [`RegistrationForm`](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/forms.html#base-form-classes), revisa la documentación de dicho formulario, por eso no funciona el registro y de hecho debería darte error.